# Visa to U.K., Italy and France

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, south-african-citizens

Myself, husband and two kids want travel to the Uk in June 2017 and are also planning a couple of days in Italy and France what visas do we need? We are South Africans.

Answer (score 2):

[You need separate visa for both the Schengen area (Italy and France part of your journey) and the UK.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_South_African_citizens) For more details do some own research first, e.g. google or search our archives.